# make_shared "evidence" vs default construct

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers

make_shared allocates single block for object and reference counter. So there is an obvious performance benefit using such technique.

I made simple experiment in VS2012 and I was looking for 'evidence':

```
std::shared_ptr<Test> sp2 = std::make_shared<Test>();
std::shared_ptr<Test> sp(new Test());
// Test is a simple class with int 'm_value' member
```

when debugging I got in locals view something like this (some lines are deleted)

```
-   sp2 shared_ptr {m_value=0 }  [make_shared] std::shared_ptr<Test>
+   _Ptr    0x01208dec {m_value=0 } Test *
+   _Rep    0x01208de0 make_shared  std::_Ref_count_base *

-   sp  shared_ptr {m_value=0 } [default] std::shared_ptr<Test>
+   _Ptr    0x01203c50 {m_value=0 } Test *
+   _Rep    0x01208d90 default  std::_Ref_count_base *
```

It seems that **sp2** is allocated in **0x01208de0** (there is a ref counter) and then in **0x01208dec** there is an Test object. Locations are very close to each other.

In second version we have **0x01208d90** for ref counter, and **0x01203c50** for object. Those locations are quite distant.

Is this proper output? Do I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the output shown is correct.

In the case of `sp2`, created through `make_shared<>()`, there is one block of contiguous memory containing the reference counter and the allocated object. This is why the two addresses are close and this is also one of the main reasons why `make_shared<>()` exists (to perform only **one** allocation rather than two).

In the case of `sp`, instead, you allocate the object separately through `new Test()` and then construct the `shared_ptr` object. The constructor of `shared_ptr` has to issue a new allocation for the reference counter. For this reason the address of the pointed object and the address of the reference counter are distant.

Comment: great :) I know the difference between those two methods, but I was looking for evidence in the memory addresses of those pointers.

Comment: @fen: Well, you found that evidence :)

Answer (score 8):

If you read [cppreference's page for `make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), they say:

> This function allocates memory for the `T` object and for the `shared_ptr`'s control block with a single memory allocation. In contrast, the declaration `std::shared_ptr<T> p(new T(Args...))` performs two memory allocations, which may incur unnecessary overhead.

So this is the intended behaviour and you interpreted it properly.

And of course, it makes sense; how could the `shared_ptr` control the allocation of an object you already allocated? With `make_shared`, you leave it in charge of allocating the object, so it can allocate space your object wherever it wants, which is right beside the counter.

*Addendum*: As Pete Becker noted in the comments, §20.7.2.2.6/6 of the Standard says that implementations are encouraged, but not required, to perform only one allocation. So this behaviour you observed should not be relied upon, though it's safe to say you have nothing to lose and something to gain if you always use `make_shared`.

Comment: The quoted text doesn't reflect the requirements correctly. Implementations **are encouraged** to do only one memory allocation, but that is not required.

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you, I updated my answer with a reference to the Standard conveying what you mentioned.

Comment: "it's safe to say you have nothing to lose and something to gain if you always use make_shared" Nearly, but not quite always: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113594/weak-ptr-make-shared-and-memory-deallocation

Answer (score 2):

> Is this proper output?

Looks like it.

The whole point of `std::make_shared` is performance - dynamic memory allocations are relatively expensive and doing an extra allocation just to hold the reference counter can be rather wasteful. Therefore, `std::make_shared` allocates a slab of memory large enough for *both* the object and the counter, and then just initializes the object (using [placement new](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222578/533120)) in its correct place within that slab.